# Convert SQL Server Varbinary field to MYSQL, keeping data intact

Tags: php, mysql

I was given the daunting task of converting a ASP website to PHP and SQL Server to MySQL, and I ran into an issue that hopefully somebody can help

I have a user table which has a password field with datatype Varbinary(128), are using pwdencrypt to encrypt the password.

Is there a way to transfer that over to MySQL, and somehow i need to be able to keep the password intact... how can i go about that? any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

[pwdencrypt](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd822791.aspx) is a hash function, therefore, recovering the passwords isn't directly possible.

However, a quick Google query of pwdencrypt reveals that it has some serious security flaws and should be avoided.

How about notifying your users that you're changing systems and that a new password is required?

When a user first attempts to login on the new system, tell them to check their email for a secure link to setup their new password. That way their account can't be stolen in the database change.

Comment: I had this feeling that it wasn't going to be possible, I appreciate your feedback and unfortunately some users don't keep good records on their email address, but I think i know how i can work around that..

Thanks again